# filtering table using jquery function and dropdown select

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show and hide rows according to selected value in drop down. After user selects `user_name` I was able to hide this user row in table using a button, but I want to show and hide rows after select without clicking a button and I can't get it to work.

This is my working function with a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $('select[name=select1]').val()) {
                //hide the matched row rather than remove it
                $(this).parent("tr:first").hide();
            }
        });
        $('select[name="select1"]').on('change', function() {
            $("tr").show();
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the not working function after trying to avoid button use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("selectedName").change(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $('select[name=select1]').val()) {
                //hide the matched row rather than remove it
                $(this).parent("tr:first").hide();
            }
        });
        $('select[name="select1"]').on('change', function() {
            $("tr").show();
        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the second one?

Comment: If you show your HTML too it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: did you mean `$(".selectedName").change()` or may be `$("#selectedName").change` in the second code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not valid in the second code block:

`$("selectedName")` If selected name is a class then you need `$(".selectedName")`, or if its an id then `$("#selectedName")`.